# How would I go about efficiently digitizing intersecting polygons from a georeferenced map by snapping vertices in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, polygon, intersection, georeferencing, digitizing

I have a map I've georeferenced in QGIS that has a lot of intersecting and adjacent polygons. I want to efficiently snap the vertices together as I draw the polygons because I don't want overlaps and because I have a lot of polygons to draw. I've turned on snapping in "Project -> Snapping Options" but as I'm drawing polygons the vertices of nearby polygons don't show up. Drawing rough overlapping polygons and then going back with Vertex Editor is way too tedious. Example map below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I hadn't turned on the "Line Endpoints" options in the snapping toolbar